# TypeError: undefined is not a function react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

When I try to run the app, it crashes with the error below? I tried several methods for clearing the cashes, including uninstalling the resent package I installed on the app, but I couldn't figure out what was causing the error or how to fix it.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:203:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.2.5:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:247928:3 in global code

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:370:8 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

The following are the recently installed packages:
@react-native-community/datetimepicke
moment

the follwing is my env

- Node: 16.15.0
- Yarn: 1.22.15
- expo: 45.0.0
- react: "17.0.2"
- react-native: "0.68.2"

[image: TypeError: undefined is not a function]

[image: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.]

Comment: Please share some code around your problem.

Comment: Before anything else, I'd recommend running 'expo install' if you are on expo. Most of the time such errors occur when dependencies are not sitting right with each other.    By looking at the error log in the red screen, it seems something is not right with your redux store configuration. Can you please edit the post above and share the store code?

Comment: @dev404 There was a typo error on the Redux Store. Now it's fixed, thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Good luck